# $X$ be Banach space , $T \in \mathcal B(X)$ be an open map , $Y$ be a closed linear subspace of $X$ ; is the restriction of $T$ on $Y$ an open map?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space , let $T$ be a continuous open linear map from $X$ to $X$ , let $Y$ be a closed linear subspace of $X$ , then is $T_o$ , the restriction of $T$ on $Y$ , is an open map ? Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No it is not true. Consider $Vect(e_n,n\in N)$ endowed with $\|\|_{\infty}$. Let $T$ defined by $T(e_n)=e_{n-1},n>0, T(e_0)=0$. $T$ is surjective, thus the open mapping theorem implies that $T$ is open. Let $Y=Vect(e_0)$. The restriction of $T$ to $Y$ is not open.

Comment: This example is not a proper counterexample. Because $Y$ is closed it is also a Banach space. $T(Y)=\{0\}$ is closed in the original space and $T|_Y$ is bounded.  So, by the open mapping theorem $T|_Y$ is also open.

Comment: so $\{0\}$ is open in $Vect(e_0)$ ?

Comment: We say $T: X \to Y$ is open if it take open sets in $X$ to open sets in $T(X)$. Here $T(X)$ is given the subspace topology (topology induced from $Y$). In this particular case because $T(X)$ is singleton it has discrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have answer for this question.

With the observation that $l^1$ embeds isometrically in its double dual $(l^1)^{**}$ which is the space of finitely additive signed measures on $\mathbb{N}$ with bounded total variation, we define $T:(l^1)^{**} \to (l^1)^{**}$ on the finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ (which is a ring of sets) by $$T(\mu)(A)=\sum_{n \in A}\mu(n)/n $$ Then, this extends to a measure on $\mathbb{P}(\mathbb{N})$ by Caratheodory extension theorem. This is a bounded linear operator with $\|T\| \leq 1$. $l^1$ is complete, so it is closed in $(l^1)^{**}$ The restriction of $T$ to $l^1$ is $T((x_n))=(x_n/n)$ and it is not open. However, $T$ itself is open by the open mapping theorem because $T$ is surjective.