# Restriction of A Continuous Linear Operator to A Continuous Linear Operator on a Closed Subspace

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a "proof" for the following problem:

> Suppose $X$ is a Banach space, the operator $T \in L(X,X)$ is open, and let $X_0$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Further the restriction $T_0$ of $T$ to $X_0$ is continuous. Is $T_0$ necessarily open?

I found a counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697127/x-be-banach-space-t-in-mathcal-bx-be-an-open-map-y-be-a-closed-lin).

What went wrong in my "proof" then? --

> $T_0$ is continuous $\implies$ $X_0 \times T(X_0)$ is closed by closed graph theorem $\implies T(X_0)$ is closed because graph is closed so it must be closed in each of its components $\implies T_0$ is open by open mapping (because range is closed)

Comment: Between which spaces does $T_0$ map? $T_0 : X_0 \to X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X_0\times T(X_0)=\{(x,Ty)\vert x,y\in X_0\}\neq \{(x,Tx)\vert x\in X_0\}=\mathrm{Graph}(T\vert_{X_0})$. (Otherwise every operator with closed graph would have to have closed range, which is certainly not true.)